# I have a data frame with 10 columns and thousand of rows. I want to replace 4th column (value<=0.05) with NA. How can I do this using R script

Tags: r, replace, conditional-statements, na

I have a data frame with 10 columns and thousand of rows. I want to give conditional format(if value<=0.05) then replace cell with NA. How can I do this using R?

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO isn't a free code writing service. Please show that you've made some effort.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
 is.na(df[,4]) <- df[,4]<=0.05
```

Or a faster option is

```
 df[,4] <- NA^(df[,4]<=0.05)*df[,4]
```

If we use `data.table`, the `:=` would be more efficient

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[V4<=0.05, V4:=NA] #assuming that the 4th column name is 'V4'
```

Comment: Thank you very much.Actually I used subset command to filter the values greater than the threshold (0.05) value.                                                    dd <- read.csv("10min_S1~S3.csv")
DF <- subset(dd, v4 >= 0.05)                                                                             But it make error when I tried to plot the subset data frame (DF). Therefore, I tried to set NA for v4 >= 0.05.

Comment: @Thilak That is different from the question you posted.

Answer (score 2):

@akrun has a brilliant solution. Just adding more for reference.

```
df[,4][df[,4]<=0.05] <- NA
```

Or for speed

```
replace(df[,4], which(df[,4]<=0.05), NA)
```

Comment: Though, my solution looks good, your take would be faster and even more faster might be to use `replace` with `which`

Comment: A few days ago we did one like that. I'll add it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30329374/replace-0-in-matrix-with-na/30330054#30330054